# AVERAGEIF Text criteria

Tags: excel

Hy guys, I am trying to make an average in Excel that would look like this,

```
if(average>80){
    System.out.println("You're good to go");
}
else {
     System.out.println("You still need work"); 
}
```

Is this possible in excel and how can I do this in Excel?

Comment: What fields average do you want to take? And where do you want the message which are in System.out.println?

Comment: That was just an example :). I want to do this just in Excell

Comment: In Excel, you can fill up some field or popup a Message. But there is no proper console to output a text.

Comment: I have some cells withs numbers and if the average is less than 80% I want to show message and if is grater that 80% I want to show a different message

Comment: Yes, thats possible with Macros, if you want a popup. And a formula is enough, if you want to fill up a field.

Comment: Ok, could you give me an example of such a formula?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thats possible with Macros, if you want a popup. And a formula is enough, if you want to fill up a field.

Ex. `=IF(AVERAGE(B1:B3)>40,"Good","Bad"`

This checks the average of numbers in fields from B1 to B3. If `>40`, it will fill up `Good`, else it will up `Bad`.

Comment: This is better than a macro because the response is dynamic.